# Restricting comboBox (day) selection based off comboBox (month)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, visual-studio-2013, combobox

I'm currently creating a program for an assignment which requires the use of 3 ComboBoxes containing Day, Month and Year which then use a button to tell the user how many days old the user is. I need to restrict the users entry based on possible dates and wondering if C# had an inbuilt function which manages this so the 30th of Febuary for example isn't possible.

This is my second program and I have very little understanding of syntax used in C#, my current code for the array / loop is this in case it's required.

```
string[] monthsArray = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "June", "July", "August",
                         "September", "October", "November", "December" };
for (int index = 0; index < monthsArray.Length; index++)
{
    comboBoxMonth.Items.Add(monthsArray[index]);
}

for (int i = 1917; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
{
    comboBoxYear.Items.Add(i);
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
{
    comboBoxDay.Items.Add(i);
}
```

I have no idea on how I can get the button to reassemble this into a date format I can then use to calculate the days old, I'd appreciate any advice on doing that, the calculation itself I'll try to work out.

Comment: " I need to restrict the users entry based on possible dates and wondering if C# had an inbuilt function which manages this so the 30th of Febuary for example isn't possible." will the user be entering the date of you'll provide the possible dates to chose from?

Comment: They can enter their own date using the combo boxes for day/month/year, I need some kind of verification to see the date exists.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` structure has quite a few useful features. This will give you the number of days in a month.

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
```

You can create a new Date from year, month and day like this:

```
var date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

You can also get the month names with:

```
string[] monthNames = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames;
comboBoxMonth.DataSource = monthNames;
```

Instead of adding elements one by one, you can assign an array to `DataSource` property of the combo box.

Comment: Thank you the array is more better, I can't seem to add them to the create a date function though.

`var date = new DateTime(comboBoxYear, comboBoxMonth, comboBoxDay); `

I added this to change the users input to integers to create the date as well but not sure if it's correct (Added to the combo boxes not form).

`Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxDay.SelectedItem);`

Comment: You must get the value out of the combo box! `date = new DateTime((int)comboBoxYear.SelectedItem, comboBoxMonth.SelectedIndex + 1, (int)comboBoxDay.SelectedItem);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime.DaysInMonth` function:

```
  int NumberOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2017, 3);
```

[For More Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx)